# Ambigous reference using ColumnAttribute

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

In one project, I was able to use ColumnAttribute without problems.

In another, not. I have the following class in a test project:

```
class TestClass_x
{
  [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
  public int i { get; set; }

  [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
  public string i2 { get; set; }

  public string str { get; set; }
}
```

resulting in

```
Ambigous reference:
 System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute
 System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute
match
```

I have the following references added to the test project:

- EntityFramework (v 4.4.0.0)
- Project to test
- Another project to test
- A third project to test
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Quality.Tools.UnitTestFramework (v 10.0.0.0)
- PresentationFramework (v 4.0.0.0)
- System (v 4.0.0.0)
- System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations (v 4.0.0.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using .NET 4.5? In such case you will have `ColumnAttribute` in both System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll and EntityFramework.dll. The solution should be upgrading EntityFramework to 5.0 because version 4.4 is only for .NET 4.0.